# Turning off subpixel antialiasing in Gnome 3 on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome3, fonts

I'm trying out the secondary monitor with portrait layout, and I want to disable subpixel font antialiasing.

I have both turned it off to "Grayscale" in `gnome-tweak-tool` and created a symlink to `10-no-sub-pixel.conf`:

```
 /etc/fonts/conf.d $ ll
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  34 Apr  9 10:37 10-no-sub-pixel.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-no-sub-pixel.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Apr  9 10:50 11-lcdfilter-default.conf -> ../conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Dec 11 22:51 20-fix-globaladvance.conf -> ../conf.avail/20-fix-globaladvance.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Dec 11 22:51 20-unhint-small-vera.conf -> ../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-vera.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  36 Dec 11 22:51 30-metric-aliases.conf -> ../conf.avail/30-metric-aliases.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  33 Dec 11 22:51 30-urw-aliases.conf -> ../conf.avail/30-urw-aliases.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  30 Dec 11 22:51 40-nonlatin.conf -> ../conf.avail/40-nonlatin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Dec 11 22:51 45-latin.conf -> ../conf.avail/45-latin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 Dec 11 22:51 49-sansserif.conf -> ../conf.avail/49-sansserif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  37 May 18  2011 50-enable-terminus.conf -> ../conf.avail/50-enable-terminus.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  26 Dec 11 22:51 50-user.conf -> ../conf.avail/50-user.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Dec 11 22:51 51-local.conf -> ../conf.avail/51-local.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Dec 11 22:51 60-latin.conf -> ../conf.avail/60-latin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  38 Mar 28  2012 65-droid-sans-fonts.conf -> ../conf.avail/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  35 Dec 11 22:51 65-fonts-persian.conf -> ../conf.avail/65-fonts-persian.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  30 Dec 11 22:51 65-nonlatin.conf -> ../conf.avail/65-nonlatin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Dec 11 22:51 69-unifont.conf -> ../conf.avail/69-unifont.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  41 Jan  4 11:14 70-yes-bitmaps.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 Dec 11 22:51 80-delicious.conf -> ../conf.avail/80-delicious.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31 Dec 11 22:51 90-synthetic.conf -> ../conf.avail/90-synthetic.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 366 Sep 27  2011 99pdftoopvp.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 959 Jun 28  2011 README
```

But the fonts still get antialiased to RGB:

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Here's `xrdb -query` output:

```
 ~ $ xrdb -query
*background:    #002b36
*color0:    #073642
*color1:    #dc322f
*color10:   #586e75
*color11:   #657b83
*color12:   #839496
*color13:   #268bd2
*color14:   #93a1a1
*color15:   #fdf6e3
*color2:    #b58900
*color3:    #cb4b16
*color4:    #2aa198
*color5:    #6c71c4
*color6:    #859900
*color7:    #eee8d5
*color8:    #002b36
*color9:    #d30102
*cursorColor:   #93a1a1
*customization: -color
*fadeColor: #002b36
*fading:    40
*foreground:    #657b83
*pointerColorBackground:    #586e75
*pointerColorForeground:    #93a1a1
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintmedium
Xft.rgba:   none
```

Comment: Please make that an answer, as there was `~/.fonts.conf` which was to blame! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work without the need to symlink `10-no-sub-pixel.conf`. If `xrdb -query` confirms that your settings are OK:

```
Xft.rgba:   none
```

then most likely a hidden config file (like `fonts.conf`) overrides your settings. Possible locations:

```
~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
~/.config/fonts.conf
~/.fonts.conf
```